# Python/ Selenium não está preenchendo o caractere til (~)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estou tentando usar o Python / Selenium / Webdriver para preencher automaticamente um campo de entrada na minha página do Chrome. No entanto, não estou conseguindo usar o comando "send_keys" para preencher o caractere til (~).

Eis o meu código:

```
import os
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")

browser.get("https://mywebpageaddress")

browser.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys('charles~18')
```

A página fica preenchida como "charles18" ao invés de "charles~18".

Nota: Manualmente é possível escrever "charles~18" nesse campo, através do navegador.

Alguém sabe como resolver? Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser por que o send_keys mande as teclas por uma camada antes do driver de teclado do sistema. Como o seu teclado tem o layout Brasileiro, o "~" é uma tecla muda.

Tente simplesmente mandar o "~" duas vezes, exatamente como se estivesse digitando:

```
browser.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys('charles~~18')
```

(claro que se for isso, o problema vai ser sério se o mesmocódigo tiver que rodar na nuvem, por exemplo,no servidor ou numa instância do travis)